# Como resolver esse erro ASSERT: "!"No style available without QApplication!"" in file kernel\qapplication.cpp, line 1054?

Tags: qt, qml

Quando inicio aplicação para apresentar uma gráfico apresenta-me este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
ASSERT: "!"No style available without QApplication!"" in file kernel\qapplication.cpp, line 1054
ASSERT: "!"No style available without QApplication!"" in file kernel\qapplication.cpp, line 1054

/ficheiro .pro

```
    QT += quick
    CONFIG += c++11

    # The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
    # any feature of Qt which as been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
    # depend on your compiler). Please consult the documentation of the
    # deprecated API in order to know how to port your code away from it.
    DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

    # You can also make your code fail to compile if you use deprecated APIs.
    # In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
    # You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
    #DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

    SOURCES += \
            main.cpp

    RESOURCES += qml.qrc

    # Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
    QML_IMPORT_PATH =

    # Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
    QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

    # Default rules for deployment.
    qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
    else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
    !isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

/ficheiro .cpp

```
    #include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

/ficheiro .qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

import QtCharts 2.0
import QtQuick 2.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ChartView {
        width: 400
        height: 300
        theme: ChartView.ChartThemeBrownSand
        antialiasing: true

        PieSeries {
            id: pieSeries
            PieSlice { label: "eaten"; value: 94.9 }
            PieSlice { label: "not yet eaten"; value: 5.1 }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Muito obrigado pessoal, já encontrei a resposta.

Para resolver esse problema, você deve substituir o **GuiApplication** pelo **QApplication**, o motivo para isso é o uso do QCharts

Como mostra a documentação sobre como usar os QCharts [link](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcharts-index.html)

> Nota: Os projetos criados com o Qt Quick Application do Qt Creator são
>   baseados no modelo Qt Quick 2 que usa o QGuiApplication por padrão.
>   Todas essas instâncias do QGuiApplication no projeto devem ser
>   substituídas pelo QApplication, pois o módulo depende do Graphics View
>   Framework do Qt para renderização.

Como o QCharts é seu próprio módulo, você provavelmente terá que adicionar gráficos **QT += charts** seu arquivo de projeto.